# How to debug a WCF Service Application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Newbie question. In vs2010 (.net 4.0), I used the WCF Service Application template to create a Web Application. This was then published using Web Deploy to IIS 7 residing on the same box as my client application.

How can the WCF Service Application be debugged?

I have tried this:

1. Set a breakpoint in the Service1.svc.cs code.
2. Recompile all with a debug configuration. Build target is to bin\
3. Publish the WCF Service Application project to the local IIS7 website.
4. Start the client application which calls the IIS7 WebSite.
5. Start a second instance of VS2010 in administrative mode and Attach to process w3wp.exe.
6. return to the first instance of vs and execute the method that has the breakpoint set.

Bringing back up the second instance of vs (the one that is attached), only shows "Disassembly cannot be displayed in run mode".

What did I miss? Is there a better way?

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Edit #1: I added debugging to the web.config, as:

```
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
           <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Still no luck??

Edit #2: In running the web service application project directly in its own instance of vs, I get

*"The Web project "WCFServiceApplication0" is currently configured to 
use the URL "http:/localhost:8999/WCFServiceApplication0". The Web server has this URL mapped to a different folder "C:\Nova5\WCFServiceApplication0_deploy". Would you like to remap this URL to point to the Web project's folder?"*

How should this be answered? And how did a *_deploy folder get made? Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Just start the WCF service in Debug mode in visual studio? Right click project -> Debug -> Start new Instance. Or do you need to specifically debug the deployed version?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Debugging the specifically deployed version would be best, but since I have the code to both, either way would work. Thanks.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I tried it and get: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly...." I added <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" /> and <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />       No luck. I'm missing something ???

Comment: You should be able to debug a WCF service in the same way as a normal web application hosted on IIS. The best way would be to set your VS to point to IIS and then run in debug mode. You should be able to browse http://localhost/myservice.svc which should show the WCF page. Now fire up your client application (say a windows app) that calls this WCF service and the moment the service is called i.e. the method it should hit your break point.

Comment: @Rajesh Newbie here...How do I "Point VS to localhost/myservice.svc"? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @AlanWayne You need to host your project on IIS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa751792(v=vs.100).aspx) Once hosted then press CTRL + P in VS that would show a dialog with list of processes. Make sure to check the show all processes at the bottom and select w3wp process and click "Attach"

Answer (score 0):

You can directly debug your WCF service.

> VS(Run as Adminstrator) -> Open the Wcf Project -> Properties -> Web
>   -> Point to the VirtualDirectory of IIS.
>
> Then Right click the Svc.cs -> Debug as New instance.

If you have mulitiple hostable Projects in Solution Like 1 Web and 1 Wcf, then set Multiple StartUp Project from Solution -> Set StartUp project.

Comment: Tried... Please see my above edits. So should I remap the Web project or not? Thanks  (and I do not know how it got mapped to a *_deploy in the first place?)

Comment: I don't quite follow. What is "Point to the VirtualDirectory of IIS" and how/where to right click on the svc.cs (I don't get Debug as an option).  Thanks.